# Reset USB serial device as if it has been physically reconnected

Tags: shell-script, usb, serial-port, usb-device

I have computers set up, each with a single 3DR/Sik Radio (USB) connected to receive data from a single 3DR transmitter on another machine. When this computer with the transmitting device is rebooted, the computers with the receivers lose the connection (or more precisely, the signal becomes intermittent). To fix, I need to physically disconnect and reconnect each receiver.

How may I emulate this with a script (preferably) or short C program?

Things such as:

```
tput reset > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 sane
```

do not work.

It's as if I need to cut and reconnect the power to the receivers.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580750/disconnect-and-reconnect-ttyusb0-programmatically-in-linux